# how to access custom module using t-if condition in xml odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have a custom module test and created pages called test_1, test_2, test_3.

I have inherited calendar view and wrote a condition in js like all the calendar changes should be reflected to test_1. And that is working fine.

Now i need to remove Day and Month button from test_1 page -> Calendar view.

So i am trying to write t-if condition. I dont have idea how to call model. i tried below code but it is not working.

```
<template>

    <tr t-extend="CalendarView.quick_create">
        <t t-if="widget.model=='test_1'">
            <t t-jquery=".form-group" t-operation="after">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3>Example - put fields here </h3>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </tr>


</template>
```

It is not working throws an `TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined`

How to access model in t-if condition?

Comment: you can use widget.model.get('label') insted of widget.model.

Comment: Thanks.. wat is ("label") here?

Comment: label is string in your case label = test_1

Comment: ok thank you.. i will try and get back to you

Comment: so you can write <t t-if="widget.model.get('label')=='test_1'">

Comment: i got,  Uncaught Error: QWeb2: Error while extending template 'CalendarView.quick_createNo expression given

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113981/discussion-between-iam-supreeth-and-jainik-patel).